# What are the possibilities of the order of $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Hi all Mathematics Lovers :)

Here is the question that I need you to check my attempt in solving it:

Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ , and that $|H|= 10$.

If $a$ belongs to $G$ and $a^6$ belongs to H, what are the possibilities of $|a|$?

**Attempt:**

$|a^6|$ should divide $|H|$, so it has $four$ possibilities : $ 1, 2, 5,$ or $10$.

$|a^6|= \frac{|a|}{gcd(|a|,6)}$,

so $|a|$= $gcd(|a|,6)$

or $|a|$= 2 $gcd(|a|,6)$

or $|a|$= 5 $gcd(|a|,6)$

or $|a|$= 10 $gcd(|a|,6)$

$gcd(|a|,6)$ divides $6$, so it can be $1, 2, 3,$ or $6$.

Trying with these values we conclude that $|a|$ can be one of these integers $ {{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 30, 60}} $ and so $|a|$ should be a divisor of $60$.

Right?

Comment: See |a| is a divisor of 60 can also be seen through Lagrange's theorem. Corollary to Lagrange's theorem says that if $|G|=n$ and $a \in G$ then $a^{n}=e$ and hence $|a| | n$. Here in your case $(a^{6})^{10}=e$ and hence $a^{60}$=e and hence |a||60. If you donot know Lagrange's theorem, your method and calculation seems fine.